# Binary tree get all nodes for every level

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve the following, say I have this binary tree...

```
       3
      / \
     9  20
       /  \
      15   7
```

Then I need to get all nodes at every level, so my result will be...

```
[[3],[9,20],[15,7]]
```

I believe I am getting close to a solution, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, if someone can help me with my solution that would be great, if I am on the wrong track, please let me know.

My first step was to get the depth of the tree using the following function...

```
def get_depth(self, root):
    if root.left == None and root.right == None:
        return 1
    return max(self.get_depth(root.left), self.get_depth(root.right)) + 1
```

The depth is `3`.

Next I called a function that was intended to give me the expected result...

```
def levelOrder(self, root):
    depth = self.get_depth(root)
    return self.find_comb(root, [[]]*depth, 0)

def find_comb(self, root, result, level):
    if root is None:
        return None
    self.find_comb(root.left, result, level+1)
    self.find_comb(root.right, result, level+1)
    result[level].append(root.val)
    return result
```

My thought process was, I would recurse through the tree and the `level` parameter would keep track of the current level that I am on. Then I would append all `root.val` on that level to the result at that index.

So let's say I am on level `1` (we start at 0), then the nodes at level `1` are `9` and `20`. So the result would look like `[[], [9, 20], [], []]`, and it would do this for every level of the tree. I hope my logic is clear. Instead the result I am getting is...

```
[[9, 15, 7, 20, 3], [9, 15, 7, 20, 3], [9, 15, 7, 20, 3]]
```

Comment: Your problem is in the line where you append `result[level].append(root.val)`. For instance, if `result=[[]]*3`, then `result[0].append(1)` will give you `[[1], [1], [1]]`. The order in which the nodes appear can be easily justified by tracking the recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually don't need to find the depth of the tree. You just traverse the tree, while keeping the level at which are you, let's say in `level` variable. And insert your value at `listOfLists[level]`. Of course you have to be handle the `IndexError: list index out of range`. Here's a simple implementation:

```
def levelTraversal(root, level):
    if root is None:
        return

    if level >= len(listOfLists):
        list = []
        listOfLists.append(list)
    listOfLists[level].append(root.v)
    levelTraversal(root.l, level+1)
    levelTraversal(root.r, level+1)
```

Call it like this : `levelTraversal(rootNode, 0)`

For your tree the result is :`[[3], [9, 20], [15, 7]]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Phyton but you might want to look at a BFS implementation on Phyton.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

For reference

```
# Python3 Program to print BFS traversal
# from a given source vertex. BFS(int s)
# traverses vertices reachable from s.
from collections import defaultdict
 
# This class represents a directed graph
# using adjacency list representation
class Graph:
 
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
 
        # default dictionary to store graph
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
 
    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)
 
    # Function to print a BFS of graph
    def BFS(self, s):
 
        # Mark all the vertices as not visited
        visited = [False] * (max(self.graph) + 1)
 
        # Create a queue for BFS
        queue = []
 
        # Mark the source node as
        # visited and enqueue it
        queue.append(s)
        visited[s] = True
 
        while queue:
 
            # Dequeue a vertex from
            # queue and print it
            s = queue.pop(0)
            print (s, end = " ")
 
            # Get all adjacent vertices of the
            # dequeued vertex s. If a adjacent
            # has not been visited, then mark it
            # visited and enqueue it
            for i in self.graph[s]:
                if visited[i] == False:
                    queue.append(i)
                    visited[i] = True
 
# Driver code
 
# Create a graph given in
# the above diagram
g = Graph()
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(2, 0)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(3, 3)
 
print ("Following is Breadth First Traversal"
                  " (starting from vertex 2)")
g.BFS(2)
 
# This code is contributed by Neelam Yadav
```

Answer (score 0):

Few improvements and variations from answer of @Schidu Luca

The problem is the way it was implemented, the child node loses which parent is despite we can retrieve at which level of the tree is.

#### Add mapping child -> parent

```
nodes = []

def traverse(root, level, parent):
    if not root:
        return
    if level >= len(nodes):
        nodes_level = []
        nodes.append(nodes_level)
    parent_key = parent and parent.value or None
    nodes[level].append({root.value: parent_key})
    traverse(root.left, level + 1, root)
    traverse(root.right, level + 1, root)


traverse(self.root, 0, None)
return nodes
```

#### Mapping level -> parent -> childs

```
nodes = {}
def traverse_mapped(root, level, parent):
    if not root:
        return
    if level >= len(nodes):
        nodes_level = {}
        nodes[level] = nodes_level
    parent_key = parent and parent.value or None
    if parent_key in nodes[level]:
        nodes[level][parent_key].append(root.value)
    else:
        nodes[level][parent_key] = [root.value]
    traverse_mapped(root.left, level + 1, root)
    traverse_mapped(root.right, level + 1, root)

traverse_mapped(self.root, 0, None)
return nodes
```